# Copy object using 'extend' turns the integer property to string

Tags: jquery

I have an object:

```
var seriesOptions = {
y: parseFloat($(this).find('y').text()).toFixed(2),
color: colors[index],
level : dlevel
};
```

Where  I am parsing and assigning value via reading a XML tree structure:

```
<series> <!-- $this--><y>55.34</y></series>
```

Below the code I make a copy of the object

```
series = $.extend(true, {}, seriesOptions);
```

The issue I am facing is that the "y" property gets converted from 55.34 to "55.34" (converted to string type) which makes my code behaving faulty. Is there a way I can copy seriesOptions.y to series.y as integer itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
Math.round(parseFloat($(this).find('y').text())*100)/100
```

Instead of

```
parseFloat($(this).find('y').text()).toFixed(2)
```

And your `'y'` will be `number`, not `string`.

Answer (score 2):

`.toFixed(2)` returns a string, not a number.

Comment: But if I remove .toFixed(2) I get some number as float to higher precision like 55.000332 (ex per say)

Comment: @Prakash: You could `parseFloat` the fixed-length string again.  However, not all numbers can be precisely represented in binary floating point.

Comment: The value of y needs to be rendered as a graph column bar - so precision is very important for my code

Answer (score 0):

Since toFixed() returns a `string` you could either say `parseFloat()` afterwards or start with an operation that converts the string to number automatically.

Comment: Then I will loose the .34 value which I do not want

Comment: @Prakash erm, I ment parseFloat()